# Can I use Cloudflare's SSL certificate with Mosquitto MQTT websocket?

Tags: ssl, websocket, mqtt

I use Mosquitto MQTT on my linux VPS.

In order to use it within my https enabled website I must have a valid SSL certificate. I am currently using Certbot to generate it, but I want to use a certificate that is generated from Cloudflare. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.